# JOIN com duas colunas na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Bom dia.
Como consigo fazer um JOIN, de duas coluna na mesma tabela?

Na tabela **cotação**, tem a coluna com o cpf_cnpj da **ogirem** e **destino**.

```
SELECT 
    cotacao.*,
    clienteOrigem.ID_Cliente    as origemIdcliente,
    clienteOrigem.cpf_cnpj      as origemCpfcnpj,
    clienteOrigem.isento        as origemIsento,
    clienteOrigem.suframa       as origemSuframa,
    clienteOrigem.rsocial       as origemRsocial,
    clienteOrigem.nfantasia     as origemNfantasia,
    clienteOrigem.ie            as origemIe,
    clienteOrigem.im            as origemIm,
    clienteOrigem.cep           as origemCep,
    clienteOrigem.rua           as origemRua,
    clienteOrigem.num           as origemNum,
    clienteOrigem.comple        as origemComple,
    clienteOrigem.bairro        as origemBairro,
    clienteOrigem.cidade        as origemCidade,
    clienteOrigem.codMunicipio  as origemCodMunicipio,
    clienteOrigem.estado        as origemEstado,
    clienteOrigem.pais          as origemPais,
    clienteOrigem.email         as origemEmail,

    clienteDestino.ID_Cliente   as destinoIdcliente,
    clienteDestino.cpf_cnpj     as destinoCpfcnpj,
    clienteDestino.isento       as destinoIsento,
    clienteDestino.suframa      as destinoSuframa,
    clienteDestino.rsocial      as destinoRsocial,
    clienteDestino.nfantasia    as destinoNfantasia,
    clienteDestino.ie           as destinoIe,
    clienteDestino.im           as destinoIm,
    clienteDestino.cep          as destinoCep,
    clienteDestino.rua          as destinoRua,
    clienteDestino.num          as destinoNum,
    clienteDestino.comple       as destinoComple,
    clienteDestino.bairro       as destinoBairro,
    clienteDestino.cidade       as destinoCidade,
    clienteDestino.codMunicipio as destinoCodMunicipio,
    clienteDestino.estado       as destinoEstado,
    clienteDestino.pais         as destinoPais,
    clienteDestino.email        as destinoEmail


FROM cotacao
    LEFT JOIN clientes clienteOrigem on clienteOrigem.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.origem
    LEFT JOIN clientes clienteDdestino on clienteDdestino.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.destinatario

WHERE 
    ID_Cotacao = '3'
```

Alem dos dados da tabela cotação, preciso pegar os dados da origem e do destino.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Podes colocar uma amostra do conteudo das tabelas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você chegou bem perto, acredito que seu erro está na falta de um `alias`

```
SELECT * from cotacao
LEFT JOIN clientes cliente_origem on cliente_origem.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.origem
LEFT JOIN clientes cliente_destino on cliente_destino.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.destinatario
WHERE ID_Cotacao = '3'
```

Se você quiser pegar só as  razões sociais de cada cliente seria assim:

```
SELECT cliente_origem.rsocial as rsocial_origem,  
       cliente_destino.rsocial as rsocial_destino, 
from cotacao
LEFT JOIN clientes cliente_origem on cliente_origem.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.origem
LEFT JOIN clientes cliente_destino on cliente_destino.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.destinatario
WHERE ID_Cotacao = '3'
```

Preste atenção na diferença entre `cliente_origem` e `cliente_destino`, também usei um `alias` nas colunas ficando `rsocial_origem` e `rsocial_destino`. Então no seu PHP você pega dessa forma:

```
echo $row['rsocial_origem']; /* razão do cliente de origem */
echo $row['rsocial_destino']; /* razão do cliente de destino */
```

Se quiser pegar só os dados do cliente origem é só usar `cliente_origem.*`

Comment: Ele mostra todos os dados da tabela `cotacao`, `clienteOrigem `, mas não mostra nenhum valor da tabela `clienteDestino`.

Comment: @Tiago Você verificou a integridade dos seus dados? Realmtente o valor do `cotacao.destino` existe na tabela clientes?

Comment: Sim, existem http://i.imgur.com/IcoZVqd.png

Comment: @Tiago Como está salvo na coluna destino da tabela cotação? Está sem pontuação?

Comment: Falha minha...rsrs, o campo é `destinatario` e não destino. (http://i.imgur.com/j2VDCSd.png). Agora esta mostrando os valores, mas tenho uma dúvida... Como distinguir o valor de origem e destinatario, sendo que os campos são os mesmos?

Comment: Não sao os mesmos, como o @ctgPi explicou, quando tu usa o `alias` você  cria uma "nova tabela". Se você utilizar `cliente_destino` ele só vai retornar dados do seu relacionamento `cliente_destino.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.destinatario`

Comment: Bacana! Como faria para mostrar no PHP o echo do `clienteOrigem.rsocial` e `clienteDestino.rsocial`?

Comment: @Tiago Atualizei minha resposta com um exemplo

Comment: Você esta colocando 2 selects?

Comment: O `primeiro` select da minha resposta é um exemplo, o `segundo` é mostrando como você faria pra pegar as razões sociais ambos feitos com 2 `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Editei meu codigo inicial.

Comment: Eu teria que fazer `alias` para todos os campos?

Comment: @Tiago Exatamente

Comment: Atualizei meu post. Esta dando um erro, `Unknown column 'clienteDestino.ID_Cliente' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Tiago Você escreveu errado no `LEFT JOIN clientes clienteDdestino` está com dois D, o certo é `LEFT JOIN clientes clienteDestino`

Comment: Como eu faço para incluir um outra tabela `config`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24888/discussion-between-maicon-carraro-and-tiago).

Comment: Descobrir :), Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from cotacao
LEFT JOIN clientes AS cliente_origem ON cliente_origem.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.origem
LEFT JOIN clientes AS cliente_destino ON cliente_destino.cpf_cnpj = cotacao.destino
WHERE ID_Cotacao = '3'
```

O `<tabela> AS <novo_nome>` renomeia as tabelas, e cria uma nova tabela virtual, permitindo que você faça vários `JOIN`s (inclusive `INNER JOIN`s, se for o caso) com a mesma tabela, mas em contextos diferentes.

A pegadinha é que renomear a tabela *não* renomeia as colunas da tabela; se você está puxando o resultado como um *array* associativo, você pode encontrar algum erro ou sentir a falta de algumas colunas. Você conserta isso fazendo

```
SELECT
    cliente_origem.nome AS cliente_origem_nome,
    cliente_origem.endereco AS cliente_origem_endereco,
    -- outras colunas de cliente_origem…
    cliente_destino.nome AS cliente_destino_nome,
    cliente_destino.endereco AS cliente_destino_endereco,
    -- outras colunas de cliente_destino…
    -- outras colunas de outras tabelas…
FROM …
```

Comment: Explicou bem melhor que eu :)

Comment: Ele mostra todos os dados da tabela `cotacao`, `clienteOrigem `, mas não mostra nenhum valor da tabela `clienteDestino`.

Comment: @Tiago, só complementando você também pode buscar todos os campos de uma tabela `cliente_origem.*` e depois renomear apenas os campos da segunda tabela `cliente_destino.nome AS cliente_destino_nome`. Então o campo `$row['nome']` no seu _array_ será referente a tabela "origem" e os referente a destino estarão renomeadas `$row['cliente_destino_nome']`.

Comment: Sim, e eu, pessoalmente, sou partidário de `cliente_origem.nome AS \`cliente_origem.nome\``, etc. mas eu entendo que a maioria das pessoas não gostam muito de ficar escapando os _identifiers_ na consulta em si.